# Use Camel 2.18.x version with Jboss-fuse-karaf-6.3.0.redhat-187

Tags: apache-camel, jboss6.x, apache-karaf

I am using camel-salesforce component in jboss-fuse-karaf-6.3.0.redhat-187. Camel version 2.18.x provide replay with push-topic. If the client subscription got lost we can replay the old notification.

As per Red hat component details page , JBoss Fuse 6.3 support camel version 2.17.0.

https://access.redhat.com/articles/348423

Is there any way we can use camel 2.18.x version with jboss-fuse-karaf-6.3.0.redhat-187, so we use salesforce replay.

Will highlty appreciate if someone could provide any link , document or any red hat jira issue.

We already tried different stuff

1.) Try to merge 2.18 replay classes with 2.17 , there is lot of changes in 30-40 classes so tough doable.

2.) Try to build with 2.18 classes with 2.17 jars .Still not worked with karaf

3.) Fuse 6.3 not support camel 2.18.x so directly using 2.18 not making sense.

Kindly let me know if need any further information.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No you should use the version that is shipped with JBoss Fuse, that is the certified version. Use Red Hat customer portal to get help/support with your fuse product. If there is a bug/feature in camel-salesforce you are looking for in JBoss Fuse 6.3 that is only available in later Camel release, then the Red Hat team can help you by looking into whether that can be backported and provided to you or what else you can do.

Comment: Thank you @Claus Ibsen, will raise ticket with Red Hat team

Comment: Does fuse support using a local, slightly altered, certified version? I need to use camel 2.17.4 but fuse only provides 2.18.x. I pointed maven to load 2.17.4 locally but am getting an exception when running in a local camel context (something along the lines of " Gave up waiting for BlueprintContainer from bundle"). Is it worth spending time tweaking 2.18.1, rebuilding, and adding a dependency entry in the flows pom?

Comment: I suggest to use Red Hat support / customer portal to get help with your Fuse product as they can better help you. Mixing/changing Camel versions to older is not an easy task, and its better to get an official help / patch / fix etc from them.